# How do I transfer downloaded games between two PS4?

Tags: ps4

Is it possible to transfer a downloaded game from one PS4 to another? I have downloaded Infamous: Second Son on my PS4 and a friend has bought it on his PS4. Would it be faster to move it locally rather than for him download it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do this. There is no provision to copy a downloaded game to a USB drive to enable such a transfer. Plus, the downloaded game is locked to your PSN account.